# Pandas compare values of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I want to find out if any of the value in columns mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4 and mark5 are the same, column-wise comparison from a dataframe below, and list result as True or False

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[7, 2, 3, 7, 7], [3, 4, 3, 2, 7], [1, 6, 5, 2, 7], [5, 5, 6, 3, 1]],
                  columns=["mark1", "mark2", 'mark3', 'mark4', 'mark5'])
```

Ideal output:

```
   mark1  mark2  mark3  mark4  mark5          result
0      7      2      3      7      7            True
1      3      4      3      2      7            True
2      1      6      5      2      7           False
3      5      5      6      3      1            True
```

So I came up with a func using nested forloop to compare each value in a column, does not work.
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
What's the correct way? Avoid nested forloop by all means.

```
def compare_col(df):
    check = 0
    for i in range(len(df.columns.tolist())+1):
        for j in range(1, len(df.columns.tolist())+1):
            if df.iloc[i, i] == df.iloc[j, i]:
                check += 1
    if check >= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: compare_col(x[['mark1', 'mark2', 'mark3', 'mark4', 'mark5]]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `apply` or a loop, compare the output of [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) to the number of columns:

```
df['result'] = df.nunique(axis=1).ne(df.shape[1])
```

Output:

```
   mark1  mark2  mark3  mark4  mark5  result
0      7      2      3      7      7    True
1      3      4      3      2      7    True
2      1      6      5      2      7   False
3      5      5      6      3      1    True
```

If you want a more efficient method and assuming a reasonable number of columns (less than a thousand) and numbers, you could use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) to [`sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) the values, compute the [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and check whether any value is `0`:

```
import numpy as np

df['result'] = (np.diff(np.sort(df), axis=1)==0).any(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   mark1  mark2  mark3  mark4  mark5  result
0      7      2      3      7      7    True
1      3      4      3      2      7    True
2      1      6      5      2      7   False
3      5      5      6      3      1    True
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the number of unique items of a series and its total size points to a presence of duplicated values.

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.unique().size != x.size, axis=1)
```

---

```
   mark1  mark2  mark3  mark4  mark5  result
0      7      2      3      7      7    True
1      3      4      3      2      7    True
2      1      6      5      2      7   False
3      5      5      6      3      1    True
```

Comment: Brilliant. Highly efficient!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: any(row[col] == row[col2] for col in range(len(df.columns)) for col2 in range(col+1, len(df.columns))), axis=1)
```

The problem I faced here was that you simply cant do `row[col] == row[col+1]` as that will check only subsequent ones, so you need 2 loops to check all possible value matches.